# Unable to Access Print Shares via IP Address But Can Via Netbios Name

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, network-share, netbios

Strange problem....

I have a W2003 DC also running file and print sharing. Since a reboot a couple of days ago, legacy devices that used mapped printers to this server are no longer able to connect. These legacy devices all connect via IP - \192.0.0.2\printersharename.

On closer inspection, I notice that if browse to \192.0.0.2 I can see all shares but if I double click any of the printers I get "Operation could not be completed. Either the printer name was typed incorrectly, or the specified printer has lost connection to the network." However, if I browse to the netbios or FQDN of the same server, I am able to connect to the printers without any problem. It may also be relevent that I can access the shared folders using any method without error.

The behaviour described above is evident whether I try connecting from another LAN member or from the server in question itself.

Unfortunatley the legacy devices that connect via IP cannot be changed to use the netbios or FQDN.

Any ideas?

Comment: does the server have multiple NIC's?

Answer (score 1):

Did the IP address change for some reason and the hostname is resolving to the new, correct IP while the hardcoded devices are no going to the right place?

Comment: The IP address hasn't changed. The only funny thing is that if you were to ping the server in question from itself, it resolves to the loopback address rather than the LAN address. There's a static entry in the HOSTS file for this that is needed for a legacy app to run. It's always been this way but we've never had these problems before...